# WPF How to change the IsSubmenuOpen color without disabling MenuItem dialogue box

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I am trying to copy the IntelliJ Titlebar Menu in Windows as a learning exercise.

The default color changes of a WPF MenuItem seem to be:

- Low Opacity blue background when "IsMouseOver" and not "IsSubmenuOpen"
- Low Opacity blue background when "IsSubmenuOpen"

I would like to change this behavior to this (which can be observed in IntelliJ):

- No color change when "IsMouseOver" and not "IsSubmenuOpen"
- Dark blue background when "IsSubmenuOpen"
- White foreground when "IsSubmenuOpen"

I have found code in this answer which is capable of doing this, but it also seems to disable the ability of the MenuItem to open its drop down box to reveal its children.

```
<Style x:Key="TitleBarMenuItem"  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="35 5 10 5" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#2675BF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I get these color changes without disabling the MenuItem functionality?

Comment: Without disabling the `MenuItem` functionality you need to overwrite the control template  the default style [Menu Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have there is that there's no popup for the sub menu. You're missing something like:

```
  <Popup x:Name="Popup"
         Placement="Right"
         HorizontalOffset="-4"
         IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
         AllowsTransparency="True"
         Focusable="False"
         PopupAnimation="Fade">
    <Border x:Name="SubmenuBorder"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
            Background="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1">
      <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
      </Border.BorderBrush>
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                    Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollViewer}">
        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
  </Popup>
```

Note that "IsItemsHost".

If you take a look at the templates for menu and menuitem you will notice it is very complicated stuff.

The approach I prefer is to work with content. You can put pretty much anything you like in a menuitem header.

One app I have does so with hard coded xaml. That's easier to understand than binding anyhow. Part of it looks like:

```
            <MenuItem Header="_Layers"   Style="{x:Null}">
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowBackground, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            _Background
                        </CheckBox>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                    <MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Width="160">
                                <TextBlock Text="Opacity" />
                                <Slider Value="{Binding BackgroundOpacity, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding AppSettings.ShowElevationMap, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            _Elevation Map
                        </CheckBox>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                    <MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem.Header>
                            <StackPanel Width="160">
                                <TextBlock Text="Opacity" />
                                <Slider
                                    Value="{Binding AppSettings.ElevationOpacity, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </MenuItem.Header>
```

Layers is a top level menu item.  These are templated different to their children. ( Did I mention menus are complicated ).

I offset the content so I don't need to worry about the icon column in the grid.

The styling I have might be useful to get you started.

You said this was a learning exercise so just doing it for you is presumably not exactly going to exercise your learning.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="MenuItemPanelTemplate">
    <StackPanel Margin="-20,0,0,0" Background="White"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemNoIcon">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPanelTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            Background="{x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrush}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Grid Margin="-1, 2, 0, 2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                    Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Path x:Name="RightArrow" Grid.Column="5" Width="10" Data="M0,0L4,3.5 0,7z" Fill="#FF212121" Margin="8,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" HorizontalOffset="-2" 
                    IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" 
                                                Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="#FF707070"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```